# How to set date range in shell script

Tags: shell

I am writing a code in a shell script to load data from specific range but it does not stops at the data I want and instead goes past beyond that. Below is my code of shell script.

```
j=20180329
while [ $j -le 20180404]
do
```

i have problem that my loop run after the date 20180331 till 20180399 then it go to 20180401.
i want it to go from 20180331 to 20180401. not 20180332 and so on

Comment: `'date -d"20180402" +%Y%m%d'` ?? why not just `.. -le 20180402` ? I You want to iterate over the days between two specified dates, using a string in the `+%Y%m%d` format. How do you increment `j`?

Comment: please see the edited question

Comment: j is incremented in the following manner j=$(( j + 1 )) #increase number by 1

Comment: Well, imagine, after 10 iterations, you get `20180329 + 10 = 20180339` There is no date 2018.03.39, but 20180339 is a perfect fine number. You have to take into account the number of days in months (and, well, following, the number of months in a year). Tip: don't do it yourself. Use `date --date='+1day'`. Better tip: don't store the number using `%Y%m%d` format. Store the number of seconds since epoch. Then increment using `24*60*60` seconds. And convert to `%Y%m%d` using `date --date=@<number of seconds since epoch>`

Comment: UPD_DT=`date +%d-%b-%Y`
LOAD_DT='date +%m-%d-%Y'
j=20180329
while [ $j -le 20180402 ]
do
fi
j=$(( j + 1 )) #increase number by 1
done

Comment: @KamilCuk I could not get your point but in the above comment, I posted my full code. Can you suggest the change which I shall make?

Comment: You should increment j using days. `20180329` this is just a number. When you do `+ 1` it just increment by one, as a number. You need to rollover, when the number of days get to 31 (or 28 or 29 or 30), you need to increment  the number of months `03` to `04`. You need to rewrite the whole loop

Comment: @KamilCuk See my answer: `while ... -le ...date -d "$j +1 day"...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## One simple question, 3+ not so short answer...

As your request stand for [shell](/questions/tagged/shell)

### 1. Compatible answer first

```
j=20180329
while [ "$j" != "20180405" ] ;do
    echo $j
    j=`date -d "$j +1 day" +%Y%m%d`
done
```

**Note** I used *one day after* as `while` condition is based on *equality*! Of course interpreting `YYYYMMDD` date as integer will work too:

**Note 2** Care about timezone set `TZ=UTC` see *issue* further...

```
j=20180329
while [ $j -le 20180404 ] ;do
    echo $j
    j=`TZ=UTC date -d "$j +1 day" +%Y%m%d`
done
```

But I don't like this because if time format change, this could become an issue.

Tested under [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) and [shell](/questions/tagged/shell) as `dash` and `busybox`.

(using *`date (GNU coreutils) 8.26`*.

#### 1.2 Minimize fork under POSIX shell

Before using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) *bashisms*, here is a way of doing this under **any** POSIX shell:

The power of POSIX shell is that we could use very simple converter like `date` and do *condition* over result:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

tempdir=$(mktemp -d)
datein="$tempdir/datein"
dateout="$tempdir/dateout"
mkfifo "$datein" "$dateout"

exec 5<>"$datein"
exec 6<>"$dateout"
stdbuf -i0 -o0 date -f - <"$datein" >"$dateout" +'%Y%m%d' &
datepid=$!

echo "$2" >&5
read -r end <&6
echo "$1" >&5
read -r crt <&6

while [ "$crt" -le "$end" ];do
    echo $crt
    echo "$crt +1 day" >&5
    read -r crt <&6
done

exec 5>&-
exec 6<&-
kill "$datepid"
rm -fR "$tempdir"
```

Then

```
daterange.sh 20180329 20180404
20180329
20180330
20180331
20180401
20180402
20180403
20180404
```

### 2. [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) date via `printf`

Under [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), you could use so-called *bashisms*:

Convert date to integer *[Epoch (Unix time)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)*, but two dates via one *fork*:

```
{
    read start;
    read end
} < <(date -f - +%s <<eof
20180329
20180404
eof
)
```

or

```
start=20180329
end=20180404
{ read start;read end;} < <(date -f - +%s <<<$start$'\n'$end)
```

Then using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) builtin `printf` command (note: there is `$[24*60*60]` -> 86400 seconds in a regular day)

```
for (( i=start ; i<=end ; i+=86400 )) ;do
    printf "%(%Y%m%d)T\n" $i
done
```

### 3. Timezone issue!!

**Warning** there is an issue around *summer* vs *winter* time:

#### As a function

```
dayRange() { 
    local dR_Start dR_End dR_Crt
    { 
        read dR_Start
        read dR_End
    } < <(date -f - +%s <<<${1:-yesterday}$'\n'${2:-tomorrow})
    for ((dR_Crt=dR_Start ; dR_Crt<=dR_End ; dR_Crt+=86400 )) ;do
        printf "%(%Y%m%d)T\n" $dR_Crt
    done
}
```

Showing issue:

```
TZ=CET dayRange 20181026 20181030
20181026
20181027
20181028
20181028
20181029
```

Replacing `printf "%(%Y%m%d)T\n" $dR_Crt` by `printf "%(%Y%m%dT%H%M)T\n" $dR_Crt` could help:

```
20181026T0000
20181027T0000
20181028T0000
20181028T2300
20181029T2300
```

In order to avoid this issue, you just have to *localize* `TZ=UTC` at begin of function:

```
    local dR_Start dR_End dR_Crt TZ=UTC
```

### Final step for function: Avoiding useless forks

In order to improve performances, I try to reduce forks, avoiding syntax like:

```
    for day in $(dayRange 20180329 20180404);do ...
    # or
    mapfile range < <(dayRange 20180329 20180404)
```

I use ability of function to directly set submited variables:

There is my purpose:

```
dayRange() { # <start> <end> <result varname>
    local dR_Start dR_End dR_Crt dR_Day TZ=UTC
    declare -a dR_Var='()'
    { 
        read dR_Start
        read dR_End
    } < <(date -f - +%s <<<${1:-yesterday}$'\n'${2:-tomorrow})
    for ((dR_Crt=dR_Start ; dR_Crt<=dR_End ; dR_Crt+=86400 )) ;do
        printf -v dR_Day "%(%Y%m%d)T\n" $dR_Crt
        dR_Var+=($dR_Day)
    done
    printf -v ${3:-dRange} "%s" "${dR_Var[*]}"
}
```

Then quick little bug test:

```
TZ=CET dayRange 20181026 20181030 bugTest
printf "%s\n" $bugTest 
20181026
20181027
20181028
20181029
20181030
```

Seem fine. This could be used like:

```
dayRange 20180329 20180405 myrange
for day in $myrange ;do
    echo "Doing something with string: '$day'."
done
```

### 2.2 Alternative using *shell-connector*

There is a shell function for adding background command in order to reduce forks.

```
wget https://f-hauri.ch/vrac/shell_connector.sh
. shell_connector.sh
```

Initiate background `date +%Y%m%d` and test: `@0` must answer `19700101`

```
newConnector /bin/date '-f - +%Y%m%d' @0 19700101
```

Then

```
j=20190329
while [ $j -le 20190404 ] ;do
    echo $j; myDate "$j +1 day" j
done
```

## 3.++ Little bench

Let's try little 3 years range:

```
j=20160329
time while [ $j -le 20190328 ] ;do
    echo $j;j=`TZ=UTC date -d "$j +1 day" +%Y%m%d`
done | wc
1095    1095    9855

real    0m1.887s
user    0m0.076s
sys     0m0.208s
```

More than 1 second on my system... Of course, there are 1095 forks!

```
time { dayRange 20160329 20190328 foo && printf "%s\n" $foo | wc ;}
1095    1095    9855

real    0m0.061s
user    0m0.024s
sys     0m0.012s
```

Only 1 fork, then bash builtins -> less than 0.1 seconds...

And with `newConnector` function:

```
j=20160329
time while [ $j -le 20190328 ] ;do echo $j
    myDate "$j +1 day" j
  done | wc
   1095    1095    9855

real    0m0.109s
user    0m0.084s
sys     0m0.008s
```

Not as quick than using builtin integer, but very quick anyway.

Comment: Very thorough answer.

Comment: @koziez I've just added a *POSIX Compliant* shell sample using 1 fork to `date`

Answer (score 0):

Store the max and min  dates using seconds since epoch. Don't use dates - they are not exact (GMT? UTC? etc.). Use seconds since epoch. Then increment your variable with the number of seconds in a day - ie. `24 * 60 * 60` seconds. In your loop, you can convert the number of seconds since epoch back to human readable date using `date --date=@<number>`. The following will work with POSIX shell and GNU's date utlity:

```
from=$(date --date='2018/04/04 00:00:00' +%s)
until=$(date --date='2018/04/07 00:00:00' +%s)

counter="$from"
while [ "$counter" -le "$until" ]; do
    j=$(date --date=@"$counter" +%Y%m%d)

    # do somth with j
    echo $j

    counter=$((counter + 24 * 60 * 60))
done
```

GNU's `date` is a little strange when parsing it's `--date=FORMAT` format string. I suggest to always feed it with `%Y/%m/%d %H/%M/%S` format string so that it always knows how to parse it.